# mysqldump throws: Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Every time I try to make a `mysqldump` I get the following error:

```
$> mysqldump --single-transaction --host host -u user -p db > db.sql
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM,
'$."number-of-buckets-specified"') FROM
information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'db' AND
TABLE_NAME = 'Absence';':
Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)
```

The result is a dump which is not complete. The strange thing is that the same command, executed from another host, works without throwing any errors. Did someone experienced the same problem?

I'm using mysql-client `8.0` and try to access a mysql `5-7` server - maybe that is the reason?

Answer (score 820, accepted):

This is due to a new flag that is enabled by default in **`mysqldump` 8**.
You can disable it by adding `--column-statistics=0`. The command will be something like:

```
mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --host=<server> --user=<user> --password=<password>
```

Check [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_column-statistics) for more information. To disable column statistics by default, you can add

```
[mysqldump]
column-statistics=0
```

to a MySQL config file, go to `/etc/my.cnf`, `~/.my.cnf`, or directly to `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`.

Comment: --databases <database name> for a particular database

Comment: @forthrin Answer edited to show how to make the change permanent.

Comment: There is also a setting in MySQL Workbench: Under "Advanced Options...", in the "other" section, there is a column-statistics that is set to "TRUE".  Change this to zero as suggest to disable.

Comment: MySQLWorkbench v8.0.14 does not have that setting.  What I did (on a Mac) was download an older version of MySQLWorkbench, opened up that package (Show Package contents) and pulled out its bundled version of 'mysqldump'.  I then edited MySQLWorkbench preferences to look at this version of 'mysqldump' instead of its own.  Export works just fine without having to set any flags. ref) https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91640#c484427

Comment: For anyone using DataGrip, you can right-click on the schema in the Database window, go to "Dump with 'mysqldump'", and add the `--column-statistics=0` argument to the generated argument list in the box at the bottom of the popup window.

Comment: Interestingly, the link you proved above explicitly states: "This option is disabled by default..."

Comment: as it might help someone, I had the same problem with MariaDB 10.4.12 and it also needs the same config, so I assume 10.4+ needs it

Comment: You can also just remove `mysql`, and install `mariadb` instead.

Comment: @MKlein Joining your comment, quote from the link of the answer: `--column-statistics

Add ANALYZE TABLE statements to the output to generate histogram statistics for dumped tables when the dump file is reloaded. This option is disabled by default because histogram generation for large tables can take a long time.` But in reality, `enabled` is the default, see [8.0 mysqldump does not work against 5.7 server](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100686).

Answer (score 48):

For those using MySQL Workbench, there is an "Advanced Options" button on the Data Export screen. The option "Use Column Statistics" can be disabled by setting to 0.

I have not confirmed, but the following information has been suggested to also be true:
In Version 8.0.14 it's missing.
In Version 8.0.16 it's doing this by default.

Comment: Only MySQL Workbench version 8.0.13 and after has this option to disable "Use Column Statistics".

Comment: MySQL Workbench version 8.0.14 doesn't have this option. Looks like they took it out.

Comment: Indeed, https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94294, should be back in 8.0.16...

Comment: still happen at 8.0.16

Comment: I can confirm that MySQLWorkbench v8.0.17 fixed the issue (MacOs). It was throwing this error on MySQLWorkbench v8.0.12 and upgraded. I noticed it didn't warn me about exporting data from a 5.X DB anymore and automatically appended the `--column-statistics=0` in the export command.

Comment: I am using v8.0.18 and can't find that option either

Comment: Like @Elte156 MySQL Workbench v8.0.17 fixed the issue on Windows automatically without having to modify any settings.

Comment: Same on v8.0.19, can't find the option. What the heck is going on? Oracle ffs!

Comment: No option in v8.0.20 either.  :/

Comment: I have 8.0.19. Workaround: copy the mysqldump command from the output window, remove defaults file part, add --column-statistics=0 with other options, open a command window in the mysqldump.exe parent folder and run manually, piping to a file in my documents folder (you'll get access denied errors if you just try to dump it to same folder). Example: 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE>mysqldump.exe --user=USER--host=127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers --column-statistics=0 "mantis" > "C:\users\moi\Documents\dumps\mantis.sql"

Comment: @dartacus seems to be the good solution for now, but it doesn't make any sense to use GUI if you still use the CLI

Comment: what I did was I rolled back to MySQL WB 8.0.13

Comment: @Earlee literally just an easy way of getting at the command

Comment: 8.0.22 this option is missing. Having problem with MariaDB.

Comment: 8.0.33 still doesn't have this option.  I'm also trying to work with MariaDB.

Answer (score 30):

I spent the whole day looking for a solution, and signed up here just to share mine.

Yes, this error is due to version differences.

Just download the **MySQL 5.7 ZIP Archive** from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and unzip it, then use the mysqldump.exe file from there.

If you are using MySQL Workbench, you will need to set a path to the mysqldump Tool you downloaded by going to **Edit -> Preferences -> Administration** (from left hand pane).

Hope this helps.

Comment: For Windows users, this .exe was located at: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe`

Comment: MySQLWorkbench v8.0.16 is still missing the option to set the column-statistics flag. This solution is arguably the best answer as it allows proper matching of MySQL versions in case of future issues.

Comment: I tried your solution with mysql-5.7.28-macos10.14-x86_64. It showed "Workbench was unable to get mysqldump version. Please verify the log for more information."

Comment: For MySQL Workbench CE 8.0.19 on Windows, the path is: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe`

Comment: MySQL workbench 8.0.28 is also missing this option so @DodiX 's suggestion is what worked for me. I already had wampserver installed so I just pointed the MySQL Workbench preferences to use the Wampserver's mysqldump.exe, in my case this was C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.31\bin\mysqldump.exe

Answer (score 22):

I know that I am late to the party but this was getting me crazy.
If you **want** to use a recent MySQL Workbench (tried with the newest one as of today, MySQL Workbench 8.0.20) you can patch this file:

```
plugins/wb_admin_export_options.py
```

in macOS: (`/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_export_options.py`) 
Replacing this line:

```
  "column-statistics":["Writing ANALYZE TABLE statements to generate statistics histograms.", "FALSE", "BOOL", ("8.0.2", None)]
```

with this one:

```
"column-statistics":["Writing ANALYZE TABLE statements to generate statistics histograms (set 0 to disable).", "1", "INT", (None, None)]
```

Then remove the .pyo:

rm /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_export_options.pyo

Finally, *reload* Workbench again and in the Data Export page, click on "Advanced options..." and you will see the column-statistics option again (set 0 to disable and click the Return button)

[image]

Note: you can download the [patched file from this Gist](https://gist.github.com/juananpe/73393c624790deb51df736d48e6119a7).

Comment: This patch worked for me. Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Worked like a charm on Windows 7. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well. The file ist located '/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_export_options.py' on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Works on windows 10 as well!

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer for 2022 using version 8.0.28. Better than having to use phpMyAdmin. Thanks.

Comment: this saved tons of time and only this is correct for 2022!

Comment: Works fine, but I'm wondering why `"TRUE", "BOOL"` doesn't work here? I might be misunderstanding the arguments. I'd prefer a checkbox. Also, is there some way to define the default, as I'd prefer it to be disabled by default.

Comment: Works with MySQL WB 8.0.31. Windows 10 path is `c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export_options.py`

Answer (score 8):

Easiest Work Around

When using **Mysql Workbench 8.0**

- Open the "Data Export" Tab
- Click Advanced Options  [image]
- Under the Other heading, set column statistics to 0   [image]
- Export again[image]

Best of luck!

Comment: I don't have this option in the "Other" section

Comment: @JoRouss Download 8.0.13 https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ maybe .16 version will have it again !  Otherway we use command line :-)

Comment: I ended up using @DodiX suggestion. Thanks @Francois!

Comment: Stupid workaround until 8.0.16 is out: in Advanced options check "force" so the error will be ignored. Of course this will ignore any other error

Comment: @Bostone, this solution doesn't ommit the error.

Answer (score 7):

To make [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/912677/476535) easier, you can rename `mysqldump`, make a shell script in its place and call the renamed `mysqldump` with the `--column-statistics=0` argument. Eg:

Rename mysqldump:

```
mv /usr/local/bin/mysqldump /usr/local/bin/_mysqldump
```

Save the following shell script in its place:

```
#!/bin/sh

_mysqldump --column-statistics=0 $@
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion and works in MacOSX with the Mysql Workbench, however you have to include the full path to your real mysqldump executable or it didn't seem to work. I tried ./ but still wouldn't work. Putting in the full path and the Workbench was able to run it with the stats flagged off.

Comment: for Windows, you can have the script like this `@echo OFF` `_mysqldump --column-statistics=0 %*`

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I'm using v8.0.30 and somehow they still don't have a column-statistics option. Seemingly it was removed?

Answer (score 5):

In addittion to pierlo https://serverfault.com/a/919403/586669

From within MySQL Workbench there is an option to set the path of the mysqldump executable.
(Edit - Preferences - Administration)

So you can create a .cmd (on Windows) or a .sh file (on Linux or mac) as follows:

mysqldump_nostatistics.cmd:

```
 @ECHO OFF
 "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe" %*  --column-statistics=0
```

mysqldump_nostatistics.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

_mysqldump $@ --column-statistics=0
```

Note the order of the parameters (it is different from pierlo's) : the dump command executed includes (or may include) a `--defaults-file=` option, and this *has to be* the first parameter.

Also The echo off is needed otherwise the workbench is unable to parse the command output correctly.

Comment: Thank you. This is what worked for me with MySql Workbench 8.0.31 and Bitnami WAMP 7.4.33 which uses MariaDB and mysqldump 10.4.27. Two things that didn't work: 1. Pointing MySql Workbench prefs to WAMP's mysqldump. 2. Setting column-statistics=0 in WAMP's my.ini

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem using the latest mysql workbench (8.0.23) on OSX (11.1) with mariadb.
I solved it by selecting the version of mysqldump found in the mariadb package.

/usr/local/mariadb/mariadb-10.1.37-osx10.13-x86_64/bin/mysqldump

Comment: That works. On linux just make sure MariaDB version of mysqldump is in your PATH, or edit the path in Workbench's Preferences -> Administration

Comment: On Windows I found the file in the `mariadb-10.5.5-winx64.zip\mariadb-10.5.5-winx64\bin` folder of the ZIP file download

Answer (score 4):

I use XAMPP and MySQL Workbench does warn about a version mismatch. I set MySQL Workbench to point to the XAMPP's mysql.exe and mysqldump.exe.

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Administration and set the path for each.

This works at least for version 8.0.14. So for others you may want to avoid using the bundled version of mysql and mysqldump.

Comment: Easy and Clean. It works with WampServer too and on Windows.

Comment: and if the path is something like /usr/local/bin/mysqldump which is hidden in Finder, use cmd+shitt+g to open that location

Comment: The Xampp version worked great for me too!

Comment: Using the xampp version will also get rid of the "mysqldump version mismatch" error I was getting.

Answer (score 4):

There a couple of answers above here that refer to renaming the mysqldump binary and creating a wrapper script. This is a terrible approach.

The correct method (in bash) is to alias the command in your .bashrc

```
alias mysqldump="mysqldump --column-statistics=0"
```

Answer (score 2):

To macOS you need the older version (8.0.13) to see the "column-statistics",
because I test the version 8.0.14 and 8.0.15 and both not showing the "column-statistics".

So, to adjust the "column-statistics" use the version 8.0.13 https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.13-macos-x86_64.dmg

Answer (score 1):

From **MySQL Workbench version 8.0.14** you don't have the option to disable `column-statistics`

You can do that in [version 8.0.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7si62.png)

But you have an option to do it by [**enabling** `delete-master-logs` in version 8.0.22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phtXs.png)

- `--delete-master-logs` has the same effect as the `RESET MASTER` SQL command.
- `RESET MASTER` deletes all binary log files listed in the index file, resets the binary log index file to be empty, and creates a new binary log file. This statement is intended to be used only when the master is started for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

For those using DBeaver check the Local Client is set to create the dump. See next images for reference:

Access to local client selection:

[image: Access to local client selection]

Local clients available:

[image: Local clients available]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with MySQL workbench latest edition, I resolved it using the mysqldump command line

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump --column-statistics=0  --user=USERNAME --host=REMOTE_HOST --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 DATABASE_NAME > c:\temp\dump.sql --password
```

Replace USERNAME, REMOTE_HOST, DATABASE_NAME with your names.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, you can get rid of `mysql` and install `mariadb` instead. This eliminates the new feature that was introduced in mysql 8.

Comment: This helped me, thank you. I working with AWS Aurora and it looks like it more complaint with the MariaDB than with the original MySQL

Answer (score 1):

If using a MariaDB backend with MySQL Workbench 8.0.31 CE use need to download the native MariaDB binaries for your system from https://mariadb.com/downloads/community/ and specify them in MySQL Workbench.

For example, if you are on 64-bit Microsoft Windows OS perform the following:

1. Goto https://mariadb.com/downloads/community/
2. On the above page, select your Operating System
3. Community Server --> Verison (latest GA) --> OS (MS Windows 64-bit) and click on download
4. Run the Install Shield just downloaded, and make sure "MariaDB Server -> Client Programs" is enabled.
5. Run up MySQL Workbench
6. Select the menu: Edit -> Preferences...
7. Select "Administration" in the left hand column
8. Update "Path to mysqldump Tool:" to be C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.10\bin\mariadb-dump.exe
9. Update "Path to mysql Tool:" to be C:\Program Files\MariaDB
   10.10\bin\mariadb.exe

No more performance statistic errors or any other divergent issues down the line between MySQL and MariaDB.

This has been posted for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I'm using mac-OS. By the way, there was `[mysqldump]
column-statistics=0` fields in `my.cnf` file that is placed under the `/usr/local/etc` directory. Deleting that field fixed the issue. (not: mysql version is 5.7 and installed via homebrew).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, it occurs when I merge multiple data tables to the existing schema from other schema and export merged data to self contained script file. I did try to change the column-statistics=0,but result was following,

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --host=loalhost --user root --passwod
mysqldump: unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
```

So I hadn't help. I analyze the MySQL log I found that

```
2019-01-21 11:31:30 1050 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-01-21 11:31:30 4176 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.
```

its complaining about the size of the innodb_buffer_pool_size. I did make it to 24MB. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS I fixed this by overriding the bundled mysqldump:

1. Install mariadb, e.g. `brew install mariadb`
2. Navigate to MySQLWorkbench > Preferences > Administration
3. Set the mysqldump path to the one you just installed, e.g. `/opt/homebrew/bin/mysqldump`

---

Note: to find the full path to mysqldump, you can run `which mysqldump` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Since i cannot comment the actual answer from user:cristhiank, i'm adding a slight variation of the actual answer. In my case i had to change it in `/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf` and i had to leave it in the `[client]` section so not adding a `[mysqldump]` section.

So for me this was working `/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf`

```
[client]
column-statistics=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench 8.0.31 on *Advanced Options* tab now exists new option "*Force*", use it to skip errors like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

For Ansible users use:

```
mysql_db:
 ...
 dump_extra_args: --column-statistics=0
```

In my case it ignores ~/.my.cnf and /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

Copy the mysqldump command from the output window, remove the defaults file part, and add `--column-statistics=0` with other option

Open a command window in the `mysqldump.exe` parent folder and run the command manually, piping to a file in my documents folder (you'll get access denied errors if you just try to dump it to same folder).

**Example:**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE>mysqldump.exe --user=USER--host=127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers --column-statistics=0 "mantis" > "C:\users\moi\Documents\dumps\mantis.sql"
```

Comment: This solution was written by @dartacus several years ago. I'm converting it into a formatted answer since it worked for me and was buried underneath a bunch of other comments.